# Distribuição log-normal em python

Tags: python, gráfico

Eu estou a tentar ajustar a distribuição log-normal a estes dados mas não sei como descobrir a média, o desvio-padrão e ajustar a curva da distribuição em Python (estou a usar o Jupyter no Anaconda). Já tinha tentado fazer isso com a distribuição normal, mas olhando melhor para o gráfico, parece que o que se ajusta mais aos dados é uma distribuição log-normal em vez de uma normal. Poderiam dizer-me como posso alterar o código e colocar uma distribuição log-normal em vez de normal, se faz favor, para o mesmo conjunto de dados?

```
#amostra 22A
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

df=pd.DataFrame({'frequencia_relativa': {'0-1': 0.282, '1-2': 0.316, '2-3': 0.171, '3-4': 0.068, '4-5': 0.085, '5-6': 0.026, '6-7': 0.026, '7-8': 0.009, '8-9': 0.009, '9-10': 0.0, '10-11': 0.0, '11-12': 0.009}})
df=df.reindex(['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7',
       '7-8', '8-9', '9-10', '10-11', '11-12'])
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [15,8]
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=df.index, height=df.frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.9)
ax.set_xlabel('Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', fontsize=22)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequência relativa', fontsize=22)
x_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
#normal com média 2,232 e variância 1.88, conforme planilha
ax.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.888), linewidth=3)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: substitua `norm` por `lognorm` no código. Veja documentação: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

Comment: @Lucas não estou a conseguir. Está a dar-me um gráfico estranho. Talvez seja porque não sei calcular a nova média e desvio padrão. Como posso calcular isso para este conjunto de dados e distribuição? Será que poderias colocar a tua hipótese como resposta se faz favor? Muito obrigada pela tua paciência e ajuda, sem ti não estaria a aprender tanto como tenho aprendido

Answer (score -2):

Sua variável X ocorre no ponto médio das classes, X=[0.5,1.5,2.5, etc...,11.5 ] - a distribuição parece ser log normal com média possivelmente na classe 1.5 nesta escala, porém, se for mesmo log normal, deves procurar a média em Ln(x).

Transforme X em Ln(X); nesta escala a distribuição deve ser normal, mas também estará assimétrica por falta de resolução do histograma (por sub amostragem possivelmente); daí você retira o Ln(média) e o Ln(desvio padrão), gera um outro vetor Ln(X) mais refinado, calcula as frequências relativas usando a distribuição normal padrão em Z (média zero, desvio 1) e leva de volta este vetor para o espaço da sua variável X usando X = exp(Ln(média) + Z * Ln(desvio padrão)).

Seguindo este procedimento encontrei média de 0.67 e desvio de 2.59 em X. Para isso, usei tentativa e erro, uma vez que otimização não levou a bons resultados. Veja que na sua modelagem, a média está na realidade apontando para o desvio padrão.